# Python packages documentation - gdata

Tags: python, youtube, gdata

i am writing a code that gets a youtube video UR, gets its id and then displays all info related to it.
i came across this method: gdata.youtube.YouTubeVideoEntry - but could not find any fully descriptive documentation (searched through the Google official gdata site for python - http://gdata-python-client.googlecode.com/hg/pydocs/gdata.youtube.html#YouTubeVideoEntry).
I found a few examples that printout some info using the above object, bu i am looking for all info available.
Am i looking at the correct object for it?
Any idea on other possibilities?

Thanks in advance...

Comment: I am assuming that you want to know all the attributes for that object, right? You can always use dir(name_of_the_object) but also have a look here: http://code.activestate.com/recipes/137951-dump-all-the-attributes-of-an-object/

Comment: when you say, 'all info', what do you really mean? the video resolution? the codec(s)?

Comment: Thanks, indeed i was looking for a list of attributes. Thank you George!